# Graylog 2.3.2 API tokens :No configuration available for access tokens

Tags: graylog2, graylog, graylog3

I am not sure how to configure graylog 2.3.2 to get an API token for my admin user?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generate a token with the API - like written in the documentation:

http://docs.graylog.org/en/3.0/pages/configuration/rest_api.html#creating-and-using-access-token

Comment: do you know if api token can be used to publish msg to graylog?

Comment: no - that tokens are given to ACCESS the API/UI of Graylog. If you want to restrict who can ingest message you like to use a collector/input that can work with client certificates and use that for auth.

Comment: Few more questions: Lets say I'd like to log messages to graylog, what are the ways to do this: 1. sending msg without authentication and 2. sending with authentication using username & password? Or any others ways?  Can I send msg to https without username and password authentication? Thx in advance !!!

Comment: The options given in the documentation aren't present in the UI for my instance.  I'm logged in as an admin, however in the users list page there are only "edit" and "delete" buttons.  The "more actions" dropdown isn't present.

Comment: he @Scott you did not share your Graylog Version - but I guess that you do not have a version with that feature.

Comment: Sorry I should have specified. We are using "Graylog 2.5.1+34194da". Since the original post was about version 2.3.2, I assumed that the screen should have existed by our version. I was eventually able to get my API token using the API lol. I couldn't just call the API with my username and password because we are using an oauth proxy, but luckily we kept 1 local admin account around and I was able to ssh to the box and use those credentials to run the generate API token API. Talk about a chicken and egg!